# "At least I thought" vs "or at least I thought" vs "or I thought"

Tags: phrase-usage

Which phrase is more common in sentences like these:

> I knew the man—at least I thought I did.
>
> I knew the man—or at least I thought I did.
>
> I knew the man—or I thought I did.

Or maybe they are equaly common and their meaning is pretty much the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all mean much the same. The middle one is rather redundant, so I would not use that in writing. The meaning of the first is clearest, so that would be my preferred expression.